# Min-height, min-width on different image orientations to fill div

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, css

In a bigcartel account, I have an image inside a div that runs through a loop. The HTML format basically is like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="product">
    <a href="...">
     <img />
     <div class="product_info"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS has a bunch of preset code, but I added it this at the end to overwrite it:

```
.product, .product img {
  max-width:210px;
}
.product{
  height:210px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.product img{
  min-width:210px;
  min-height:210px;
}
```

It displays nicely with portrait oriented images with overflow hidden, but with landscape oriented images it squishes the width. Is there another property I can add to make it not squish horizontally?

I tried to run it through a conditional CSS javascript, but Bigcartel doesn't seem to run it. 
The url is http://atwatertest.bigcartel.com

Comment: From the first rule you have `max-width:210px` and from the last you have `min-width:210px`. This translates to `width:210px` since it cannot be bigger nor smaller than that. You need to rethink the logic you want for resizing.. (*try to explain what you want to happen so we can suggest solutions*)

Comment: Is it possible to have the width/height set on the image tag?  Or any additional CSS classes added like "landscape" or "portrait"?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you set `max-width` or `min-width`, add `height: auto`, and likewise for `max/min-height` and `width:auto`. This will tell the CSS engine to resize images proportionately.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what percentage of the screen you want the height of the image to take. Then use the **vh** property.
**Example**
If you want the height of the image to take 1% of the screen height at any given point use **1vh**.

```
img {
height: 1vh;
width: 1vh;
}
```

That implies that the image will always take 1% of the screen. That makes it resize accordingly.